# How to Change URL of index action for all controllers in CakePHP 3.3.3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

My Cake 3.3.3 app uses a bootstrap dropdown menu in the top navbar.

When I go the index for any controller, for example:
http://localhost/myapp/items or 
http://localhost/myapp/people

The dropdown menu doesn't work.  It works for Add, Edit and View actions, e.g.:
http://localhost/myapp/items/view/27 etc works fine.  But the in index for any controller it does not.
The menu DOES work if I add something to the URL, such as:
http://localhost/myapp/items/ or 
http://localhost/myapp/items/index

I believe it has something to do with the URL... the dropdown toggle `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">` doesn't work in the url http://localhost/myapp/items.

My question is therefore: How do I set the default URL for index to be either 
http://localhost/myapp/items/ or http://localhost/myapp/items/index?

I'd like this to be the default for all the controllers.

Thanks in advance for any advice!
D.

Comment: I highly doubt that bootstrap dropdowns are affected by the current URI in any way whatsoever. Your problem is most likely to be found somewhere else in your code, which may somehow be linked to the current URI, and that's what you should fix instead of trying to workaround it. I'd suggest that you share a little more info, ideally enough so that people are able to reproduce your problem, code, possible errors, debugging attempts, bootstrap version, where/how you include it, etc...

Comment: Thanks ndm.  You're right.  It was a script loading error in my template.  I'm not sure why it only affected that one view, but after fixing that the issue goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I found I was loading my jquery and bootstrap scripts twice in my default layout template.

I'm not sure why it affected only the index (landing page) for each controller, and no other actions, but removing the extra loading of the scripts and the issue goes away.